# How React pass props from API to component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parentA and childB component
I want it click a button in parentA
then execute function to get data from API
then show on B component. that seems simple.

**Parent:**

```
  let profileData = {
    avatar: '',
    first_name: 'hey',
     ...
  };

const handleClickProfileOpen = () => {
  setIsProfileOpen(true);
   getProfileData();
};

  const getProfileData = async() => {
    let res;
    try {
      res = await....;
      if (res.code === 200) {
        profileData = res.data.data;
        ...
      } else {
        ...
      }
    } catch...
  };

return (
 <>
  <UserInfo openProfilePage={ handleClickProfileOpen } />
  <Profile profileData={profileData} />
 </>
)
```

**Child (profile)**

```
export default function Profile({profileData}) {
 return (
  <>
    <p>{profileData.first_name}</p>
  </>
)}
```

and I run it, the `profileData` is not re-render when called API, the `last_name` is always 'hey',
I tried `setState` in `getProfileData code === 200`, but causes an error:

> >>>Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.

I'm a new react programmer, if you answer, I appreciate it.

Comment: Can you describe what profileData is? How is it stored? You need to save it in a hook to trigger an update after the api call was executed.

Comment: just a object state i want to props down

Comment: I used const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState({ avatar: ''... });
 if (res.code === 200) { setProfileData(res.data.data); ...
but it's always undefined in child

Comment: u can't get the updated value to Profile using this method only way is setState ! ```const [profileData,setProfileData] = useState()``` and update the state in ```if (res.code === 200) {
        setProfileData(res.data.data);
        ...
      }```

Comment: I know but I tried setState but not working (Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.)

Comment: This means that the parent component is not displayed at the time the api through

Comment: I know why.....I set undefined to the state(res.data.data), I'm like a idiot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using functional component, you can use `useState` from react, refer to https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

E.g.,

```js
function ParentComponent() {
const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState({
    // default value if you needed, otherwise use `null` 
    avatar: '',
    first_name: 'hey',
     ...
})

const handleClickProfileOpen = () => {
  setIsProfileOpen(true);
   getProfileData();
};

  const getProfileData = async() => {
    let res;
    try {
      res = await....;
      if (res.code === 200) {
        setProfileData(res.data.data);
        ...
      } else {
        ...
      }
    } catch...
  };

  return (
    <>
      <UserInfo openProfilePage={ handleClickProfileOpen } />
      <Profile profileData={profileData} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Above is the easiest way to handle simple react state, you can find other state management libraries when you state become more complicated.

Comment: this is the way I used at first time, but it warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function. (WTH is it saying, I am crazy